# Solspace Freeform upload multiple image files

Tags: templating, plugin-freeform, files

I've had a good look around and can't find any template reference to uploading multiple images with Freeform.  In settings i've allowed for 5 files in 'File Count'.  I'm using the following template code but it only allows a single file.

```
<div class="field row field13">
  <label for="uploadPhotos" class="label">Upload photos of the fault</label>
  <input id="uploadPhotos" type="file" name="uploadPhotos.handle[]" placeholder="Please provide any images of the fault" />
</div>
```

Any guidance appreciated.

Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be 2 errors in your code. `name="uploadPhotos.handle[]"` should be `name="uploadPhotos[]"`, assuming your field name is `uploadPhotos`. The `handle` part is unnecessary, unless you were using it like `name="{{ uploadPhotos.handle }}[]"`, but it's redundant since you already are calling the handle to get the handle (but makes more sense when you're automating the template code).

Secondly, you need to specify `multiple` attribute if you wish to have more than 1 file uploaded.

The correct code should be:

```html
<div class="field row field13">
  <label for="uploadPhotos" class="label">Upload photos of the fault</label>
  <input id="uploadPhotos" type="file" name="uploadPhotos[]" multiple />
</div>
```

Comment: Apologies for the delayed reply - This worked for me thanks :)